# How to get the file data from an html input form of type file, using refs in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<input type="file" ref="file" size="45" />
```

i wanted something like this from the [MSDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) `fileInputElement.files[0]`
but i did this `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.file).files[0]` 
but no data was returned.

Comment: Can you paste the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.refs.file.files[0]
```

works well for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" name="sendAttachment" 
       ref={(input) => {  this.sendFile  = input; }}
       onChange={  (e)=>{this.sendAttachment(e)  }} />

sendAttachment(e) 
{
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.sendFile.files[0]);
}
```